# How can i add variable to URL

Tags: jquery, variables, addition

How can I insert two variables to the URL in the code? I have already inserted the variable filtertype at the end of the URL. The word "slug" in the url should be replaced by the variable slug.

```
$('body').on('click','.profile-filter',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var filtertype = $(this).data("filtertype");
    var slug = $(this).data("slug");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/profile/timeline/post/slug/?' +filtertype,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#profile_content').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhqr, data) {
            _toastr_new(data, "top-full-width", "error", false, '.toastr-notify', 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: take a look at template literals -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I am understanding the question right, but simple Javascript concatenation won't work? like so:

```
url: '/profile/timeline/post/'+slug+'/?'+filtertype,
```

Comment: I see, let me check more

Comment: Can you make sure that the value of slug is not "%20slug%20" ? I mean can you console.log it before making the ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I guess you want to concat strings, you can use pure js like this

```
'/profile/timeline/post/'+ slug +'/?' + filtertype
```

Or use ES6 template literal feature

```
`/profile/timeline/post/${slug}/?${filterType}`
```

Comment: i get the wrong URL, /profile/timeline/post/%20slug%20?filtertype

Comment: If using es6 feature, make sure you are using tilde apostrophe (`) its not the same as regular apostrophe ('). - Tilde - key under ESC

Upper example should work without any problem using regular js concating. Please make sure you have correct values inside variables

Comment: that was my mistake in php, sorry